# How to trigger Ajax call after a box selection is done in python bokeh plot

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, bokeh

I have two plots, namely, plot1 and plot2.

Plot2 has BoxSelectTool enabled and I can obtain point coordinates of the  selected rectangular area using CustomJS.

Now I need to trigger an ajax call with the obtained coordinates to let server-side update plot2.

The following code snippet may help you understand my intention, although the code does not work as I expect.

```
    callback = CustomJS(args={}, code="""
        let geometry = cb_data['geometry'];
        let x0 = geometry['x0'];
        let x1 = geometry['x1'];

        (function($){
            let request={}, args = {};
            args['x_coord'] = [x0, x1];
            request['args'] = JSON.stringify(args);
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url_for('app.selection_changed') }}',
                type: 'POST',
                data: request,
                cache:false,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('.div_plot').html(response);

                },
                error: function(response){

                }
            });                
        })(jQuery);

    """)

plt.add_tools(BoxSelectTool(callback=callback, dimensions="width"))
select_overlay = plt.select_one(BoxSelectTool).overlay
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet seems one of the right ways:

Python side:

```
    callback = CustomJS(args={}, code="""
        let geometry = cb_data['geometry'];
        let x0 = geometry['x0'];
        let x1 = geometry['x1'];
        let event = new CustomEvent('MetricSelected', { detail: [x0, x1]});
        let elm = document.getElementById('metric_selected');
        elm.dispatchEvent(event);      
    """)
```

JavaScript side:

```
$('#metric_selected').bind("MetricSelected", HandleEvent_MetricSelected);
function HandleEvent_MetricSelected(event)
{
    let request={}, args = {};
    let x = event.detail;
    args['x_coord'] = [x[0], x[1]];
    request['args'] = JSON.stringify(args);
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url_for('app.metric_select_changed') }}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: request,
        cache:false,
        success: function (response) {
            $('.disc_plot').html(response);

        },
        error: function(response){

        }
    });
}
```